# MS VS 2015 C++ - Unresolved External - Invalid Symbol reference

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

First of all, I have not worked with C++ in quite awhile, but have a need to migrate an older program I wrote to the latest platform so that it works on newer hardware.

First, the program is a windows application and works on VS 2005. I copied the files to a network share for this project and did the initial build and fixed all compile errors.

During the LINK stage, I am getting the "Unresolved External" error message (LINK 2019 and LINK 2001) on a specific function.

When I select the calling function and view the "Go To Definition", the Find Symbols panel opens with 2 entries for the function: the copy on the shared drive and the a pointer to the original file.

I went into the project properties dialog and removed all inherited references to the original path, but the issue persists.

I cannot find or determine where this reference to the old function (path to the original file) is coming from.

Being a novice at this, I am stuck. I hope that I have supplied enough details to ask for help, but if you need additional details, please specify.

Any help is greatly appreciated.[image: Find Symbol Results][image: Function Hierarchy][image: Linker Error messages][image: C++ Directory Properties]

Comment: Possible duplicate:  [What is an undefined symbol and how to fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: What do you have in the `Additional Include Directories` in the project's properties -> C++ -> General? This is for the "Go To Definition" issue. For the link error, in what module is this function supposed to be implemented? Is it a part of your project? If not - do you link to it?

Comment: The additional directories specified is blank. I am hoping that the link error is associated with this invalid reference. The correct file location and module is the x:\rick\poller\poller.net\ location. All modules are in my project (with one exception but that one does not reference this function). Also, thanks Mathew, I will review that possible duplicate link and see if it helps!

Comment: Are you using your old .sdf file? I would close the solution, delete this file ans re-open; your `Find Symbol` might get fixed.

Comment: Re: LINK error - your function openDbConn() is declared in dbUpdate.h, but where is it defined? dbUpdate.cpp, I assume? Is that file also included in your project?

Comment: Vlaf, yes the dbUpate is defined in the .cpp file.I will delete the .sdf file, I did n;t try this one yet, good call! Thank you so much.